# How to put a html into flash file?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i'm making a website and the content of it is a html file so how can i open the html file inside my flash file so the navigation bar of the flash stays

position actions (the actions i used to align almost evrything)

```
stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResize);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

function onStageResize(evt:Event):void {

if(fullProjectPanelUp==true){

    fullProjectPanel.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - fullProjectPanel.width/2;
    fullProjectPanel.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - fullProjectPanel.height/2;

}

navContainer.y = stage.stageHeight-77;
navContainer.scaleX = stage.stageWidth/1225;
mainContainer.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - mainContainer.width/2;
mainContainer.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - mainContainer.height/2;

}

function onFrame(evt:Event):void {

if(fullProjectPanelUp==true){

    fullProjectPanel.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - fullProjectPanel.width/2;
    fullProjectPanel.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - fullProjectPanel.height/2;

}

navContainer.y = stage.stageHeight-77;
navContainer.scaleX = stage.stageWidth/1225;
mainContainer.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - mainContainer.width/2;
mainContainer.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - mainContainer.height/2;

}
```

and my navigation actions (the actions i used to for the navigation bar)

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;

var buttonArray:Array = new Array( );
var currentButton:Object = new Object;
var selectedSection:Number = 0;

var fullProjectPanelUp:Boolean=false;
var firstSectionUp:Boolean=true;
var secondSectionUp:Boolean=false;
var thirdSectionUp:Boolean=false;
var fourthSectionUp:Boolean=false;

var navContainer:Sprite=new Sprite  ;
addChild(navContainer);

var navArray:Array=["الرئيسية","المحتوى","المراجع","التواصل", "خريطة الموقع"];

for (var i:Number=0; i<5; i++) {

        var navItem:NavItem = new NavItem;
    navItem.x = navItem.width*i;
    navItem.nav_name.text = navArray[i];
    buttonArray.push(navItem);
    navItem.addListeners();
    navContainer.addChild(navItem);

    navItem.name = String(i);

    navItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}

function onNavClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    if(fullProjectPanelUp == true){

        removeChild(fullProjectPanel);
        fullProjectPanelUp = false;

    }

    selectedSection = Number(evt.currentTarget.name);

    currentButton.y = 0;
    currentButton.addListeners();
    currentButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

    currentButton = evt.currentTarget;
    currentButton.removeListeners();
    currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);

    animateOut();

}

function removeAllChildren():void {

    var k:uint=mainContainer.numChildren;

    while (k --) {
        mainContainer.removeChildAt(k);
    }
}

function animateOut():void {

    TweenLite.to(mainContainer, 0.6, { x:stage.stageWidth, alpha:0,         onComplete:animateIn});

}

function animateIn():void {

    removeAllChildren();
    mainContainer.gotoAndStop(selectedSection+1);

    TweenLite.to(mainContainer, 0.4, {alpha:1});

}

initialNavigation();

function initialNavigation():void {

    buttonArray[0].y = -10;
    currentButton = buttonArray[0];
    currentButton.removeListeners();
    currentButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onNavClick);
}

var navSide:NavSide = new NavSide;
navSide.x = navContainer.width;
navSide.width = stage.stageWidth - navContainer.width;
navSide.alpha = 0.7;
navContainer.addChild(navSide);

navContainer.y = stage.stageHeight-67;
```

and if u need the files

["the files"](http://www.mediafire.com/?msyu0z23ss76v9v)

Comment: You can't open html files inside Flash, at least not in the way you want to do here, as I understand it. Flash text fields have some rudimentary HTML rendering support, but not enough for this case, I would say. If you want to use the Flash navigation and show HTML pages, I guess using frames or iframes is your best bet.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö How i can do it then

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö do u know how to open a html file in flash like a box in the middle of the flash ?!!!

Comment: @aymanzzz What you're trying to achieve isn't possible in Flash. Simple.

Comment: You can't open a html file in a box in Flash. What you could possibly do instead is to divide your main HTML file into frames (HTML frames) where one frame would contain your Flash navigation and another frame would contain the HTML file you navigate to. So you would need to read up on HTML frames, and how to use navigateToURL() in ActionScript to target a specific frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution available would be to add an absolute container in your html page. Using `ExternalInterface.call` you may send coordinates from the AS3 to the javascript and set the position of the html container.

Note that your swf's wmode must be set to opaque or transparent to allow html content on top of flash.

Comment: I'm going to `+1` this purely for its creativity (ignoring that it's a complete twist of words).

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for a mobile app with adobe AIR this can indeed be done and is very easy.
Just use the StageWebView: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_using_stage_web_view.html